# problem while inserting hindi text in mysql using wildfly

Tags: java, mysql, wildfly, sqldatasource

I am trying to insert some hindi text in mysql table from my web page. The server I am using is wildfly. I can insert the hindi text from mysql console. But when the same query is run from my bean using datasource, it is inserted as '???????'. This led me to believe that there is some issue with mysql confinguration in wildfly. Below is the snippet of my datasource

```
            <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jaas/testds" pool-name="testds" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql:<HOST>:3306/DB?autoReconnect=true</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <connection-property name="zeroDateTimeBehavior">
                    round
                </connection-property>
                <connection-property name="jdbcCompliantTruncation">
                    false
                </connection-property>
                <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <security-domain>EncryptedPassword</security-domain>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

I am thinking that I need to set some connection property to enable language support, but I am noty sure about this. Can someone pleae help me?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think its a configuration issue. Its probably an encoding issue, that the data you send from web-page is not encoded properly.

Comment: No, I have prints on the server side which is ok. After inserting the text in db, it is stored as ??????

Comment: have you mentioned the encoding in your connection string? Please share the code how you create the connection and insert the data

Comment: ok, https://developer.jboss.org/thread/199128 works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open Your MySql table and find the column in which you want to insert Hindi text
and click on change and find    Collation column and    select **utf8_general_ci**.
(To prevent this type of error you should choose utf8_general_ci in Server connection collation column  during database creation ).

[image: you can get help from a screenshot from where you have to change column]

Comment: Yes, This is necessary along with the change in https://developer.jboss.org/thread/199128